# Cosmos DB SQL API - Optimistic concurrency control - usage of etag

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using CosmosRepository( not ReactiveCosmosRepository)  and i want to handle concurrency using the "_etag" property.
I added the "_etag" property to my document as :-

```
class User {

@Id
private String id;

@JsonProperty("_etag")
private string tag;
}
```

When i do the below :

```
document.setTag("ABCD");
repository.save(document)
```

The document in cosmos db looks like :-

```
{
 "id" : " some random uuid ",
 "_etag" : " again some random uuid",
 "_ts" : "123123123"
 "_rid": "random string"
 "_self": "again random strings"
 "_attachments" : "attachments/"
}
```

**BUT** i was expecting **_etag** to look like :

```
{
...
 "_etag" : "ABCD" 
...
}
```

Because i did `document.setTag("ABCD")`

When i took the db-generated _etag and added it in my PUT methods (obviously to update the record) , the save(update) was successful even if the tag did not match.

Do i need additional configuration ? Won't a simple repository.save() with etag field defined in the document suffice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/documentcrud/sync/DocumentCRUDQuickstart.java#L210

Jcoder you are on the right track in using the above sample as the basis of your solution.

Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB is built on top of the Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK which is where CosmosClient comes from. I understand, you are trying to accomplish the above without using the Java SDK and CosmosClient directly. But actually that is what we recommend you to do. In pom.xml make sure to pull in both Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK.

For another example of using both the Spring Data connector and the underlying Java SDK simultaneously, see "Custom query execution" at this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb

Comment: It worked for we with passing the etag value, and annotating with @Version. If etag matches the document is updated. Else, it fails with an exception. Thanks for the links to the documents.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actively set the value for etag in Cosmos DB. This is handled for you automatically. You only need to insert, replace, or upsert the item for it to be set.

Comment: Hi Mark, i'm referring to the 4th para of this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control . Precisely this statement : "The item’s _etag value changes every time the item is updated. For replace item operations, if-match must be explicitly expressed as a part of the request options"

Comment: The document further says :If any conflict is detected, the stored procedure will roll back the transaction and throw an exception. ........ This is a signal to the application to reapply updates and retry the original client request.

Comment: so you're saying etag handling is done internally and it is not available for configuration in my application  ?

Comment: The only thing you need to configure is to specify it-match in the request options and if it matches the update will work. If not, it will throw an exception giving you the opportunity to go fetch the item again, apply your updates again, then try the update again.

Comment: So instead of ```repository.save()``` , i should use "replaceDocumentWithConditionalEtagCheck" as mentioned here ? : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/documentcrud/sync/DocumentCRUDQuickstart.java#L210

Comment: If yes, what would be the simplest way to accomodate above code with https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-sample where i use ```repository.save()``` instead of using CosmosClient ?

Comment: That is correct use that function that does etag check. I don't know on your other question. Will attempt to get someone from that team to reply.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It worked for me by using @Version on a filed called _etag in my document class.